# Override login Authentication in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

my `laravel` version is `5.3`. I'm using built-in Authentication in `laravel` to login users.

there is a column name in user table as `status`. when it is `0` it means the user cannot login.

now I don't know how to check this column before login method/user. 
I don't want user can login when the `status` column is `0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override `authenticated()` function:

```
 protected function authenticated()
    {
      if (auth()->user()->status==0) {
          auth()->logout();
          return redirect('/');
      } 
    }
```

You can also [Manually authenticate users](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#authenticating-users) by overriding `authenticate()` function:

```
public function authenticate()
    {
         if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'status' => 1])) 
         {
             // Authentication passed...
          }
     }
```